# UserMailer failing in Delayed::Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, delayed-job

I'm trying to send an email with Delayed::Job in Rails 5 like so: `UserMailer.delay.test("my message", "email@example.com")`. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It gives this error:

`FAILED (0 prior attempts) with ArgumentError: unknown command 'h'`

or, sometimes,

`FAILED (0 prior attempts) with NoMethodError: undefined method`deliver' for false:FalseClass`

The stack trace is pretty cryptic.

I can run other methods asynchronously by appending `handle_asynchronously :some_method` after any method.

And `UserMailer.test("my message", "email@example.com").deliver_now` works fine. How can I debug this issue? Is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's because my UserMailer method was named `test`, which doesn't seem to work in Delayed::Job